# Programmatically signing in to azure ad javascript for power bi native apps

Tags: wordpress, powerbi, adal, adal.js

We need to access [power bi rest api's](http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io) and for authentication we are currently using [adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) which is working fine.But the problem is it opens up popup window for autentication.Is there some way to autenticate silently using username and password using js only as end user will not have any credentials (we need to integrate in wordpress)?

I know this can be done easly in .net but we need to do it using pure javascript any help suggestion would be appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any one else who is seeking for the answer of same question i was able to get the access token through below given api

```
"https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token"
```

with params like

```
          "client_id"=clientID
           "grant_type"= "password"
           "resource"= "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
           "username"= username
           "password"= password
```

and setting content type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`